# getting error "base class undefined" but base class appears to be defined

Tags: c++, include

In `MbusTcpSlaveProtocol.hpp` I have

```
// Package header
#include "hmtcpip.h"
#include "hmtimer.hpp"
#include "MbusSlaveServer.hpp"
```

and several lines down I have the following:

```
class
#if defined (_WINDLL) || defined(__DLL__)
   __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
MbusTcpSlaveProtocol: public MbusSlaveServer
{

  protected:

   enum
   {
      // MBAP prefix
      MBAP_HDR_LEN = 6,
      // Header is MBAP prefix + 1 byte function + 1 byte address
      HDR_LEN = MBAP_HDR_LEN + 2,
      // Frame is same as header for this protocol
      FRAME_LEN = HDR_LEN,
      // TCP max. message size is data size + frame length:
      MAX_MSG_SIZE = MAX_DATA_SIZE + FRAME_LEN
   };

   char bufferArr[MAX_MSG_SIZE];


   public:
```

When I compile with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, I get an error on the `MbusTcpSlaveProtocol: public MbusSlaveServer:` line which says:

> Error    C2504   'MbusSlaveServer': base class undefined

and yet I can go to the definition in the `MbusSlaveServer.hpp` file (below) by right clicking on the base class and "go to definition":

```
class
#if defined (_WINDLL) || defined(__DLL__)
   __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
MbusSlaveServer
{

  protected:

   enum
   {
      PDU_SIZE = 253,
```

I don't understand how the compiler thinks the base class is undefined but the interface can find the definition.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a circular inclusion problem.  Do any of your headers include a header which then includes the header you started from? i.e. `MbusTcpSlaveProtocol.hpp` includes `MbusSlaveServer.hpp` which then include `MbusTcpSlaveProtocol.hpp`.

Comment: Possibly a case of circular includes, see [Undefined base class though includes present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505613/undefined-base-class-though-includes-present?rq=1)

Comment: Also, make sure you're using include guards.

Comment: By the way, see if you can create a [mcve], and you might solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Are you using namespaces?

Comment: All header files are using include gaurds and the following using statements are declared in the main .cpp file: #using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.Core.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::IO::MemoryMappedFiles;

Comment: My problem turned out to be similar to the one linked by Bo Persson. I have learned that circular includes, even with include gaurds, can reorder header content such that definitions appear after references. I was able to solve my problem by deleting an include statement, but I suppose I could have also used forward declarations. Also, I have learned that just because MS Visual Studio can find a definition does not mean that the compiler can. Thanks to all for the input.